# I am getting no response from the MongoDB server installation in the Kubernetes cluster after from C# program after running aprox. more than 1 hours

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, mongodb-.net-driver, bitnami

I have a MongoDB server deployment in a Kubernetes cluster using the image version docker.io/bitnami/mongodb:7.0.2-debian-11-r7. The MongoDB server is accessed by a C# Console Application deployed in the same cluster with 5 replicas, using the MongoDB.Driver (2.22.0).

The application continuously queries one or many collections in MongoDB, specifically using the GetParemeterDetails function below:

```
public BsonDocument GetParemeterDetails(string companyId, string applicationId, string id)
{
    MongoClient dbClient = new MongoClient(mongDBConnectionstr);
    var database = dbClient.GetDatabase($"derivedparameters{companyId}{applicationId}");
    var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Derived_Paramater_Config");
    var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("Derived_Parameter_Id", id);
    var project = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Exclude("_id");
    var funcLogDocument = collection.Find(filter).Project(project).FirstOrDefault();
    return funcLogDocument;
}
```

After approximately 1 hour of continuous operation, the application experiences no response from the MongoDB server.

Additional Information:

The issue appeared after upgrading multiple components in the project, including MongoDB server version and driver versions.
I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this MongoDB connection issue. Thank you.

Workarounds Tried:

1. Thread cancellation after 1 minute and retry, observed multiple retries failing without any response.
2. Switched to FindAsync method and awaited, delaying the occurrence of the issue to around 14 hours.
3. Attempted to downgrade/upgrade MongoDB server version (previously 4.4.11) and driver versions (previously 2.12.0) without resolving the issue.

Comment: what you've provided does not say anything valuable. You should (placed in order of necessary): 1. Provide connection string. 2. Provide driver side logs. 3. Provide service side logs

Comment: ConnectionString used: mongodb://useradmin:abc1234@mongodb.mongodb:27017?authSource=admin&readPreference=primary&directConnection=true&ssl=false&maxPoolSize=15&minPoolSize=5

There are no logs with errors, we are not just receiving any response from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Never use `directConnection=true`. There are very few and very specific cases where this option might be required.

> There are no logs with errors, we are not just receiving any response from the server.

it's not possible, if the driver doesn't receive any server response, it will be timeout error.

You didn't provide any logs (which can be collected on the [driver](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/csharp/current/fundamentals/logging/) and [server](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/log-messages/) sides), but because you specify `directConnection=true`, I assume this is what happens:

0. You use a replica set with few nodes.
1. At the application starting, you connect to specific mongo server (the one which is primary at that time). And settings `directConnection` forces a driver to use only this server.
2. At some point, the server goes down which makes the previous primary => secondary (or even unavailable). Then you specify `readPreference=primary` which means that you also force driver to allow reading only from the primary which now is a different server than initially. So, because of these 2 connection string options, in this case the driver can't do any operation and fails.

you should specify [replicaSet](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/#replica-set-option) option (instead `directConnection`) to the connection string. In this case, when failover will happen on the server side, the driver will be able to find a new primary

Comment: I think there is a bit of confusion. Let me clarify that, My Mongo Server deployment has only 1 replica and the application service has 5 replicas.

Comment: I'm experiencing an issue where my MongoDB server (with only 1 replica) is not responding within a reasonable timeframe, causing delays in my Kafka consumer. The Kafka consumer wrapper waits for 10 minutes to complete processing a received message, and if no response is received from the MongoDB server within this time frame, a Kafka exception is thrown.

Comment: Despite checking logs, there are no error messages or specific details explaining the lack of response from the MongoDB server. The MongoDB operations are encapsulated within a Kafka consumer wrapper, and the delay in MongoDB responses is affecting the timely commitment of Kafka messages.

Comment: `with only 1 replica` - I guess you mean, a replica set with a single node? Still do not use `directConnection`. Also, settings a single node replicaset is wrong, useless and strongly not recommended. What happens if you remove directConnection and change readPreference on 'primaryPreferred'? Overall, you didn't provide enough information: 1. You didn't mention kafka and how you configure it. 2. You didn't provide any logs. 3. You have to provide a server state on the time when the issue happens. Connect to the server at that time and call: `{ hello : 1 }`.

Comment: At this time I doubt anything else can be recommended here.